# Why is this not toggling the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, toggle

I have a thing on my website for net neutrality, for where when you close the banner, it sets a cookie so that it won't open again. I've checked if the cookie sets and it does, I've also checked to see if fetching the cookie works, and that does. When the webpage loads, its supposed to check if the cookie has anything in it, and if it does, then it will toggle the banner to make it invisible but if it's null, then it won't do anything. Here's the code:

```html
    <center>
      <div id="savebanner" style="border:5px solid red; width:60%;"><img src='image/savebanner.jpg' onclick='window.open("https://www.battleforthenet.com")' width="100%"><br><button style="background-color:red; color:white" onclick="denySaveBanner()">No thanks, I want to pay more for a worse internet</button>
        <button
          style="background-color:green; color:white" onclick="window.open('https://battleforthenet.com');">Show me how I can help</button>
      </div>
    </center>


    ...(rest of page)...


    function denySaveBanner() {
      var expire = new Date();
      expire = new Date(expire.getTime() + 604800000);
      document.cookie = "saveBannerClosed=here; expires=" + expire + ";path=/";
      $('#savebanner').toggle();
    }

    function testBanner() {
      var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
      if ((offset >= -180) && (offset <= 240)) { //Europe and America
        var visit = GetCookie("saveBannerClosed");
        if (visit == null) {

        } else {
          $('#savebanner').toggle();
        }
      }
    }
    testBanner();
```

I get no errors in the debugger and I know it had worked before, but it just recently stopped working all of a sudden. Thanks to anyone who knows what's wrong.

Comment: Not an explanation, but shouldn't the cookie timestamp be an Unix timestamp?

Comment: Why are you using `.toggle()` instead of `.hide()`?

Comment: Did it work for the last 2 weeks, then stop yesterday?

Comment: The other person who works on our website used toggle.

Comment: No reason to use toggle as you just want to hide.

Comment: And no, it hasn't been working for a few weeks, maybe 2 or more?

Comment: Could be running twice, never use .toggle when you want hide something that you aren't sure is already visible.

Comment: any chance that the banner's display is none?

Comment: Ok, ill change it to hide when i fix it

Comment: Just checking as quite often thing happen to stop working on the 13th... due to date formats where the system thinks you want the 13th month instead of 13th day (not the case here).

Comment: check if it works with the .hide

Comment: Ok i changed it to hide, ill tell you of that fixes it

Comment: It didn't fix it

Comment: does the debugger gets to the else's content?

Comment: Yes, there are no errors in there

Comment: can you put the debugger on both testBanner and denySaveBanner and check how many times they are getting executed?

Comment: Only once at start

Comment: Both? because denySaveBanner shouldn't be executed

Comment: No, sorry. denySaveBanner is only executed when you press the button to execute it

Comment: Alright. and if you open up the console and execute $('#savebanner').toggle() does it work?

Comment: What do you mean by add execute?

Comment: just type it in the console and press enter.

Comment: Oh, for some reason the computer i was just using decided not to display anything past execute so i was really confused

Comment: Yes it works. It also works with hide